# I want to use dialogflow to create a prototype of an Instagram chatbot that uses the Messenger API for Instagram

Tags: instagram, dialogflow-es, chatbot, instagram-api

I want to use dialogflow to create a prototype of an Instagram chatbot using the Messenger API for Instagram, but the Messenger API for Instagram is not recommended on the official dialogflow website.
Please let me know if there is a way.

What I need is the ability to send DMs in some form of auto-response to users' DMs, comments, Stories actions, and Stories mentions.

We are also considering adding a feature that would allow us to send DMs to users who responded to DMs that they are interested in jackets when new jacket products are released.

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)